# What is ActionListener and how to use it to handle the Enter key?

Tags: java

i  get a trouble when i write this code for a jButton to open new jfame and all that is by using the "Enter key" but it didn't work ,this the code i have writen :

```
 if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
     Chooser ch = new Chooser();
       ch.setVisible(true);
}
```

but i got the answer that contains that the enter key dosen't work with the event it's just with th Action Listner why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `KeyBinding` and then register the action with the component, or in this case the button. Here is a little code snippet that does it.

```
     JButton btn = new JButton("Open Window"); //creates the button
     //registers the KeyStroke with the button
     btn.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ENTER"), "released");
     //creates an action for the component
     Action exit = new AbstractAction() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn, "You pressed the enter key");
        }
    };
     //registers the Action with the corresponding keystroke on the button component
     //@param exit is the action to be performed
     btn.getActionMap().put("released",exit);
```

I suggest you read about using KeyBindings [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)